# Android - Two decimal points

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a currency converting app. I want get answer in two decimal point.

Here is my code :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void pri (View view){

        EditText amount = findViewById(R.id.amount);

        Double amout =  Double.parseDouble(amount.getText().toString());

        Double samount = amout * 180;


        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "S. " + rsamount.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Log.i("price", amount.getText().toString());

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's not C, that's Java.

Comment: try this. 
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

Double samount = df.format(amout * 180);

Answer (score 1):

here is the function in kotlin to convert number in two decimal point.

```
fun roundOffDecimal(number: Double): Double? {
        val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
        df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING
        return df.format(number).toDouble()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
EditText amount = findViewById(R.id.amount);

int amout =  Integer.parseInt(amount.getText().toString());

int samount = amout * 180;

String converted = new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(samount);
```